# Homeomorphism between the group of $S(O)_{2}$ and the $S_1$.

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

During an exam I had to prove the following:

"Let there be a dynamical system of $n=2$ dimensions and let the eigenvalues that correspond to it, to be imaginary with their real part equal to zero. Then, there exists a homeomorphism between the monoparametric group which is defined by the flow of the system and the $S_1$."

Thank you!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I would like to prove that this homeomorphism exists.